# How to divide each element in a row by corresponding row value?

Tags: r

(I want to divide each element in a row by corresponding row value. Denominator should the value of "Ac" when row element is present.

```
Ac    V1  V2  V3   V4  V5  V6  V7
6.6  NA  NA  NA   NA   0  5.6  5.2
8.4  NA  0   82.5 31   0  0    1.1

Output:

V1 V2    V3        V4       V5                            V6               V7     
NA 0/8.4 82.5/8.4 31/8.4  (0*6.6+0*6.6)/(6.6+8.4) (5.6*6.6+0*8.4)/(6.6+8.4) (5.2*6.6+1.1*8.4)/(6.6+8.4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We divide all the columns except the 'Ac' column with the 'Ac', then `summarise_all` to return  the `sum` if any non-NA element is present or else return `NA`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  transmute_at(-1, list(~ ./Ac)) %>% 
  summarise_all(list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else sum(.,na.rm = TRUE)))
#  V1 V2       V3       V4 V5        V6        V7
#1 NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 0.8484848 0.9188312
```

---

It can also be done in a single step

```
df %>% 
  summarise_at(-1, list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else (sum(./Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) ))
#  V1 V2       V3       V4 V5        V6        V7
#1 NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 0.8484848 0.9188312
```

#### Update

Based on the comments,

```
df %>% 
    summarise_at(-1, list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA
       else if(sum(is.na(.)) == 1) (sum(./Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) 
      else (sum(Ac* ., na.rm = TRUE)/sum(Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) ))
#  V1 V2       V3       V4 V5    V6    V7
#1 NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 2.464 2.904
```

---

Same method can be translated to `data.table` as well

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA 
      else sum(x/Ac, na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols = 2:ncol(df)]
#   V1 V2       V3       V4 V5        V6        V7
#1: NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 0.8484848 0.9188312
```

Updated data.table solution

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA
       else if(sum(is.na(x)) == 1) (sum(x/Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) 
      else (sum(Ac* x, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) ), .SDcols = 2:ncol(df)]
#   V1 V2       V3       V4 V5    V6    V7
#1: NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 2.464 2.904
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Ac = c(6.6, 8.4), V1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    V2 = c(NA, 0), V3 = c(NA, 82.5), V4 = c(NA, 31), V5 = c(0, 
    0), V6 = c(5.6, 0), V7 = c(5.2, 1.1)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I modify this if only one row is NA divide the number by corresponding "Ac" as shown in my Output column V3.

Comment: @Nude For me your output is showing `82.5/8.4#
[1] 9.821429`like the one I have

Comment: just updated my Output. For Columns V5,V6 and V7 I need to divide by sum of both "Ac" if both rows have numbers.

Comment: @NUdu  Isn't that the code is doing right now.  Do you need `df %>% 
  summarise_at(-1, list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else (sum(./sum(Ac), na.rm = TRUE)) ))`

Comment: No. the code is not doing that. For example, column V7 the the Output should be 2.904. ((5.2*6.6)+(1.1*8.4))/(6.6+8.4). This method only if data exists in both rows otherwise your method is correct.

Comment: @NUdu Okay, so you need a sum product

Comment: Yes. ONLY IF both rows have numbers otherwise divide by corresponding "Ac" value.

Comment: @NUdu  What about this `df %>% 
   summarise_at(-1, list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else (sum(Ac* ., na.rm = TRUE)/sum(Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) ))
  V1 V2   V3    V4 V5    V6    V7
1 NA  0 46.2 17.36  0 2.464 2.904`

Comment: No. for example answer for column V3 should be 9.82 (82.5/8.4) because only one row has data. But, V6, V7 is correct when both rows has data. I prefer the data table method.

Comment: @NUdu  Not clear about the logic.  You are doing `82.5/8.4` what about the multiplication part?

Comment: @NUdu  May be this `df %>% summarise_at(-1, list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else if(sum(is.na(.)) == 1) (sum(./Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) else (sum(Ac* ., na.rm = TRUE)/sum(Ac, na.rm = TRUE)) ))
  V1 V2       V3       V4 V5    V6    V7
1 NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 2.464 2.904`

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly I am after. Can you help me with the data table answer please?

Answer (score 2):

Your data:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(V1 = c(rep(NA,4), 0, 5.6, 5.2),
                 V2 = c(NA, 0 , 82.5, 31, 0, 0, 1.1))

df <- df %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Ac = c(6.6, 8.4)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Ac, V1:V7)
df
```

```
> df
   Ac V1 V2   V3 V4 V5  V6  V7
1 6.6 NA NA   NA NA  0 5.6 5.2
2 8.4 NA  0 82.5 31  0 0.0 1.1
```

- The answer:

```
resp <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Ac) %>% 
  t %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(V1_1 = V1/df[1,1],
                V2_2 = V2/df[2,1]) %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(resp = ifelse(is.na(V1_1) & is.na(V2_2), NA,
                              sum(V1_1, V2_2, na.rm = T))) %>%
  dplyr::select(resp) %>% t %>% as.data.frame()
resp
```

```
> resp
     V1 V2       V3       V4 V5        V6        V7
resp NA  0 9.821429 3.690476  0 0.8484848 0.9188312
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the loop and convert output to dataframe or list

```
for (i in 2:8){

    temp1 = df[1,i]/df[1,1] 
    temp2 = df[2,i]/df[2,1]
    temp= ifelse(!is.na(temp1)&!is.na(temp2), temp1+temp2,
          ifelse(is.na(temp1) &!is.na(temp2), temp2,
          ifelse(!is.na(temp1) &is.na(temp2), temp1,NA)))
    assign(paste0("V", i-1), temp)
    rm(temp1, temp2, temp)
}
output <- c(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7)
output <- data.frame(output)

     output
1        NA
2 0.0000000
3 9.8214286
4 3.6904762
5 0.0000000
6 0.8484848
7 0.9188312
```

Comment: If data frame has additional columns change the index in loop (2:8).

Answer (score 0):

We could divide every row with the first value in the row and take column wise `sum`

```
colSums(df[, -1]/df[[1]], na.rm = TRUE)

#     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7 
#0.00000 0.00000 9.82143 3.69048 0.00000 0.84848 0.91883
```

If we want to keep the first element as `NA`

```
(NA^(colSums(is.na(df[, -1])) == nrow(df))) * colSums(df[,-1]/df[[1]], na.rm = TRUE)

#     V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6      V7 
#     NA 0.00000 9.82143 3.69048 0.00000 0.84848 0.91883
```

Comment: V1 should be NA and what would be the data table approach.

Comment: @NUdu updated the answer. Now it should also work with `data.table`.